# Reaching a variable inside of an enum element in java

Tags: java, enums

I want each element of an enum to have different variables but I can't reach them.

```
public class Employee {
public GENERAL[] general = GENERAL.values();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee e = new Employee(); 
    e.general[GENERAL.INCOME.ordinal()].salary = 10; //this line doesn't compile

}

enum GENERAL{
    INCOME{
        public int salary;
        public int tips;
    },SATIFACTION{
        //some variables
    },EFFICIENCY{
        //some variables
    };
}

}
```

I've tried casting to `(GENERAL.INCOME)` but it didn't work. Is there a way to do it? If this is not possible, what is the best work around? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, you can initialize value only in enum constructor. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20344929/enum-properties-side-effects/20345009#20345009

Comment: No, you can change the variables after the constructor.

Comment: instance can't define members. Members are defined at class (enum) level only.

Comment: If you want different members for each instance then create different classes for each.

Answer (score 2):

Try defining variables at enum level rather than individual elements:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  MainClass e = new MainClass(); 
      e.general[GENERAL.INCOME.ordinal()].salary = 10; //this line doesn't compile
      System.out.println(e.general[GENERAL.INCOME.ordinal()].salary);
  }

  enum GENERAL{
     INCOME(0,0), SATIFACTION(0, 0), EFFICIENCY(0,0);
     int salary;
     int tips;
     GENERAL(int salary, int tips){
         this.salary = salary;
         this.tips = tips;
     }
  }
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is there will be many unnecessary variables in each element. Satisfaction will have salary, Income will have socialValues etc. This will cause extra memory usage and will clutter each element with unnecessary variables.

Answer (score 1):

This is because INCOME is an anonymous subclass of GENERAL, it is something like this

```
static class GENERAL {
    public static GENERAL INCOME = new GENERAL() {
        public int salary;
        public int tips;
    };
}
```

there is no way to access fields of an anonymous class in Java (except reflection)

Comment: I have no experience with reflection. Would it solve this problem?

Comment: It would work, but it would be a bad solution, I just explained why you cannot access salary

Answer (score 0):

This is the cleanest way I can do it. I still have an array that I can use to iterate. Each element of the General holds its own variables. Each element has an ordinal to use as the index number.

The problem with this approach is this cannot make use of `GENERAL.values()`. If a new element is added later, It must be added to the `getList()` method manually and in the correct order. It is easy to make mistakes when adding new elements to the code.

```
public class Employee {
public Object general[] = General.getList();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee e = new Employee();

    General.Income i = (General.Income) e.general[General.Income.ordinal];
    i.salary = 10; //eclipse doesn't let me to combine these 2 lines into 1 expressions. 

    System.out.println(i.salary);

    // following lines demonstrates that the salary of the e.general[General.Income.ordinal] is changed. Not just the i.
    General.Income t = (General.Income) e.general[General.Income.ordinal];
    System.out.println(t.salary);

}

public static class General {
    public static Object[] getList() {
        Object general[] = { new Income(), new Satisfaction(), new Efficiency() };
        return general;
    }

    public static class Income {
        public static final int ordinal = 0;
        public int salary;
        public int tips;
    }

    public static class Satisfaction {
        public static final int ordinal() {return 1;}//using method instead of int saves memory. (8 bytes I think. Neglettable).
        // some variables
    }

    public static class Efficiency {
        public static final int ordinal = 2;
        // some variables
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Use braces to combine those two lines:
`((General.Income)e.general[General.Income.ordinal]).salary=10;`

Answer (score 0):

If each enumeration would contain a single value, why not use that?

You can even add a method to retrieve some descriptive name:

```
enum General {
    INCOME, SATIFACTION, EFFICIENCY;
    int value = 0;

    String getName() {

        switch(this) {
            case INCOME:
                return "salary";

            case SATIFACTION:
                return "etc";
        }
    }
}
```

These can be set/get by `General.values()[i].value` and `General.INCOME.value` or add `setValue(int value)` and `getValue()` methods and make `value` `private`.